# pass yes, seed no: how to deal with reinstalled metamask?

Tags: metamask

i have the login data for my metamask account but no seed available. is there a way to access the accountafter reinstall? I'm kinda new and didnt think id'd need the passphrase aas long as i know the login. I treid to reinstall but it keeps asking me for the seed...

Answer (score 0):

To recover your account you need either the mnemonic (12 or 24 words) or the private key (long string looking like 0x23acf234123....). If you just have your password to enter MetaMask, then I'm sorry, but that's not enough.